# How to prevent xslt from adding xlmns attributes to elements?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Error"
      internalLogFile="internal-nlog.txt">
  <targets async="true">
    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="exceptions"/>
    <logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I have defined a xslt like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:t="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/t:nlog/t:targets">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />
            <target xsi:type="Bugsnag" name="bugsnag" apikey="xxx" AppType="${{app}}" ReleaseStage="Development" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/t:nlog/t:rules">
        <xsl:copy>
            <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="bugsnag" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This does the transformation almost the way I need, except that it adds `xlmns` and `xlmns:t` attributes to the output like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><nlog autoReload="true" internalLogLevel="Error" internalLogFile="internal-nlog.txt" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets async="true">
    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
    <target xsi:type="Bugsnag" name="bugsnag" apikey="xxx" AppType="${app}" ReleaseStage="Development" xmlns="" xmlns:t="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" /></targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="bugsnag" xmlns="" xmlns:t="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="exceptions" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

How can I prevent xslt from automatically adding that namespace to the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:t="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="t">
```